# when a hosting mentions 100mbps bandwidth, what does it mean?

Tags: linux, performance, bandwidth, network-speed

Most of web hostings say 100mbps bandwith, does it mean 100mbps upload and download combined ? what is the share between upload speed and download ? is 50 50 ? or 40 60 ? or etc ? Can anyone explain please ?

Comment: -1 because I think it's fundamentally unanswerable.  As MDMarra has pointed out, it *ought* to mean FD 100Mbit/s, but hosting companies use weasel words all the time, and you're going to have to ask each hosting company what exactly they mean by what they say.

Comment: I downvoted this and here's why: Hosts typically mean different things in their marketing material than industry standard terms mean. They abuse terms like "bandwidth" to mean "monthly data transfer" and 100Mb is rarely a vanilla full duplex 100Mb connection. Because of this, the answer always fundamentally boils down to "ask your host what they mean." I didn't vote to close it. Asking here *first* shows a lack of research which warrants a downvote, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

In general networking terms, it means that there is a 100Mbps full duplex connection. This means 100Mbps in *each* direction.

In practice, hosting companies use all kinds of slanted terminology and marketing mumbo jumbo to suck you in. You're best off getting the terms in writing from any host you're considering, since they don't always mean what they say.

Comment: +1 Also, just because you've got a X Mb connection to the server doesn't guarantee you'll actually get a X Mb connection to the Internet. When discussing link speeds you'll want to ask about ABR and CBR (DBR outside the US). ABR is the fastest your connection is capable of going (If they refuse to quote/estimate this number, run and never look back); CBR is what they'll guarantee (CBR guarantees always cost more, don't be surprised if they don't offer CBR at all).